# Email Goes to junk in Hotmail

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, amazon-web-services

Email is sent using Amazon simple Email service form my website.
 When an email is sent to any Yahoo or Gmail address, it is delivered to *Inbox*; but when it is sent to Hotmail,it is delivered to *Junk*.
Why only  Hotmail Treats my email as junk?

Comment: I had a similar case, and it appears it was the sender name that was causing the spam score to increase. More details there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998465/76673

Answer (score 0):

> When an external user sends email messages to an Outlook.com account,
>   SmartScreen® filter technology evaluates the content of the messages
>   and assigns each message a rating based on the probability that it is
>   a junk email. This rating is stored as a message property called a
>   spam confidence level (SCL) within the message itself. The SCL rating
>   stays with the message as it is sent to other anti-spam protection
>   layers within Outlook.com. Rules inside Outlook.com are set to handle
>   email messages with various SCL ratings. If a message has an SCL
>   rating lower than a certain threshold, it is considered to be spam,
>   and a rule then deletes the message rather than sending it to the
>   user's junk email folder. If the message has a higher SCL rating than
>   the threshold, the email is delivered to the user's junk email folder
>   rather than to the inbox.

https://mail.live.com/mail/junkemail.aspx

Comment: How can i find SCL rating for the email, website sending to customer?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is a email service provider specific thing but you can do below checks

1. Ensure valid sender email address
2. Try not to use keywords like gift, prize etc. which are preferably spam activities

Try using https://litmus.com which may help on this/ rendering email in different email clients

Answer (score 0):

Not all the Anti-Spam system depends only on 3rd party blacklists. Major email service providers builds their own reputation table in addition with the use of major 3rd party blacklists like spamhaus, barracuda etc. In your case, you are using Amazon SES to send mails.
I, myself found enormous marketing mails coming from Amazon SES. If the reputation of your email service provider is bad in hotmail  then it may trigger the suspicious level of your mail regardless of your email service provider reputation at other blacklist providers. In addition to this, if your subject, body content contains some suspicious words then your mail will end up in junk folder.

Answer (score 0):

Most emails sent from third party applications such as Wordpress, Joomla, or Amazon get diverted to junk and sometimes they fail and get stuck behind a security layer. I know for a fact with Wordpress Contact Form 7, this is the case many times.

After so many years and finally attending a seminar for this particular issue, I finally was able to solve this problem specifically for Hotmail (Outlook.com).

Before you do anything ensure your SMTP settings in your web config file (ASP.NET) are written correctly or in case of plugins (Wordpress) make sure the fields are filled correctly. This means ensuring these are the settings you are using for Outlook:

```
From: your email ("asdf@outlook.com")
From Name: "Your name or company name"
Host: smtp.live.com
Type of Encryption: TLS
SMTP Port: 587
SMTP Authentication: Yes
Username: Same you use to login (usually the complete email address)
Password: Enough said there
```

> **IMPORTANT** - Send a test email even if it fails. The point is to trigger an activity in Outlook and have them flag it as an
>   unauthorized connection

Now, to the fix:

- Go to Outlook.com
- Login
- go to Account Settings
- Choose Security & Privacy
- Click on "See my recent activity"
- The most recent activity should be the fail attempt. Authorize it as a trusted connection.

Done!

Re-test and you shall see your emails showing in the inbox as an authorized connection. Doing these steps let Outlook know that your emails from Amazon are legitimate connections and not Amazon trying to spam your account with solicitations etc.